# Testing a PreferenceActivity with Robotium

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

I am new to using Robotium and can't seem to find any answers to this on the forums anywhere.  I have a PreferenceActivity that I am trying to test.  The problem is that my unit tests fail whenever I need to click on a preference.

More specifically, I have a CheckBoxPreference that I am running some tests on.  I want to verify that when the CheckBoxPreference is checked, there are certain preferences on the screen that are enabled (not grayed out), and vice-versa.  As of right now, I can't even find the preference by using the `searchText()`/`waitForText()` methods (it is the first preference on the screen).  I have also tried using the `clickOnView()` method after getting the view of the preference from `getView()`.

It seems like the best I can do right now is to just manipulate the state of the CheckBoxPreference using Android's `setChecked()` method.  I'm assuming testing in this manner *is* possible and there is something fundamental that I am looking over, however.  Since a PreferenceActivity is also a ListActivity, I have also tried searching for related questions on testing a ListActivity to no avail.

The following couple of links gave me a good start to working with PreferenceActivities and Robotium.

- http://fyrecloud.com/index.php?topic=5.0
- http://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/detail?id=250

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
public void testEnabledChecked() throws Exception {
    CheckBoxPreference enabled = PrefTestingUtils.getCheckBoxPreference(mSolo, mActivity, 
            (String) getVal("KEY_ENABLED"));
    EditTextPreference recipient = PrefTestingUtils.getEditTextPreference(mSolo, mActivity, 
            (String) getVal("KEY_RECIPIENT"));
    EditTextPreference title = PrefTestingUtils.getEditTextPreference(mSolo, mActivity, 
            (String) getVal("KEY_TITLE"));
    ListPreference interval = PrefTestingUtils.getListPreference(mSolo, mActivity, 
            (String) getVal("KEY_INTERVAL"));

    // ensures that the preference is unchecked
    if (!enabled.isChecked()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Enabled preference unchecked, clicking on it");

        // mSolo.clickOnView(enabled.getView(null, null)); // Attempt #1
        // mSolo.clickOnText("Enabled"); // Attempt #2
        // mSolo.clickOnCheckBox(0); // Attempt #3
        // mSolo.searchText("Enabled"); // cannot find view
    }

    assertTrue(enabled.isChecked()); // AssertionFailedError here
    assertTrue(recipient.isEnabled());
    assertTrue(title.isEnabled());
    assertTrue(interval.isEnabled());
}
```

I have verified that the PrefTestingUtils functions are indeed returning valid references to the preferences.  All of the PrefTestingUtils functions are similar to this:

```
public static CheckBoxPreference getCheckBoxPreference(Solo solo, 
        PreferenceActivity activity, String key) {
    if (solo == null || activity == null || key == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getCheckBoxPreference::Null parameter");
        return null;
    }

    Preference p = activity.findPreference(key);
    if (p instanceof CheckBoxPreference) {
        return (CheckBoxPreference) p;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any help anybody can give would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I've successfully tested a PreferenceActivity before. What have you tried? You should post your current test class code, otherwise it's hard to give you pointers.

Comment: Thanks, dmon.  I have edited my post to include my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what I came up with that seems to be working.

First you need to get a reference to the CheckBoxPreference:

```
private CheckBoxPreference getCheckBoxPref(String key) {
    ArrayList<ListView> currentListViews = mSolo.getCurrentListViews();
    // get the lone ListAdapter for the PreferenceActivity
    ListAdapter listAdapter = currentListViews.get(0).getAdapter();

    int cnt = listAdapter.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        Object o = listAdapter.getItem(i);
        if (o instanceof CheckBoxPreference) {
            CheckBoxPreference pref = (CheckBoxPreference) o;
            if (pref.getTitle().equals(key)) {
                return pref;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Next, using you can click on the preference using the clickOnText() method with the preference's title.  Finally, I found that you have to sleep for some time after clicking.  I have `MINI_SLEEP` defined to 250 ms.

```
public void testCheckBoxEnabled() {
    CheckBoxPreference pref = getCheckBoxPref("Enabled");
    assertNotNull(pref);
    assertFalse(pref.isChecked());
    mSolo.clickOnText("Enabled");
    mSolo.sleep(MINI_SLEEP);
    assertTrue(pref.isChecked());
}
```

Hope this helps for anyone who should need it.

Comment: I voted up, but there is one little thing to change - getCheckBoxPref(String **key**) should be changed to getCheckBoxPref(String **title**)

Comment: In Robotium 4+, `.getCurrentListViews()` becomes `.getCurrentViews(ListView.class)`